# SQL Server Unable to Open Table or Rename

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey when I try open table I receive the message

Timeout Expired

Then when I try and rename the table I get

Rename Failed Lock Request Time out Expired

Basically I just want to delete the content of this table but in every step there is something stopping me.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to empty it, use DELETE FROM TABLENAME or TRUNCATE TABLENAME in SSMS or SQLCMD.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some running query/transaction is locking the table.  Try using [sp_who](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677668/sql-server-unable-to-open-table-or-rename) to see what activity is occuring:

```
USE master
EXEC sp_who 'active'
```

Or you can use SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are running against your DB.

[image]

Comment: Hey yup ran that and there is a lot of stuff returned there. Im basically just want to filter this down to to 1 table i.e TblError and just stop whatever is locking it and delete the contents of this table how is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

SqlACID tel you the best and easiest way to solve your problem.

truncate will work faster and effective, you will not have large archive log files,  but after you can't restore your data. it will delete permanently and the flash_got command will not help you.

if truncate does not works too after that you must recreate your table by this command 
drop table your_table cascade constraints;
-- Create table
create table your_table (col1 number, col2 varchar2(5)).

if it does not works too after this create another table like it:

create table temp_table2 as 
select * from temp_table 1 where 1=2